# TensorFlow: Does each session run initiate a different batch of data in a graph?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

Meaning to say if I have the following graph like:

```
images, labels = load_batch(...)

with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
    logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(images, num_classes = dataset.num_classes, is_training = True)

predictions = tf.argmax(end_points['Predictions'], 1)
accuracy, accuracy_update = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels)

....

train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(...)
```

and in a supervisor `managed_session` as `sess` within the graph context, I run the following every once in a while:

```
print sess.run(logits)
print sess.run(end_points['Predictions'])
print sess.run(predictions)
print sess.run(labels)
```

Do they actually call in different batches for each sess run, given that the batch tensor must actually start from `load_batch` onwards before they ever get to `logits`, `predictions`, or `labels`? Because now when I run each of these sessions, I get a very confusing result in that even the predictions do not match `tf.argmax(end_points['Predictions'], 1)`, and despite a high accuracy in the model, I do not get any predictions that remotely even match the labels to give that kind of high accuracy. Therefore I suspect that each of the result from `sess.run` probably come from a different batch of data.

This brings me to my next question: Is there a way to inspect the results of different parts of a graph when a batch from load_batch goes all the way till a train_op, where the `sess.run` is actually run instead? In other words, is there a way to do what I want to do without calling for another `sess.run`?

Also, if I were to check the results using sess.run in such a way, would it affect my training in that some batches of data will be skipped and not reach the train_op?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized there is a problem with running using separate `sess.run` in that the data loaded is always different. Instead, when I did something like:

```
logits, probabilities, predictions, labels = sess.run([logits, probabilities, predictions, labels])
print 'logits: \n', logits
print 'Probabilities: \n', probabilities
print 'predictions: \n', predictions
print 'Labels:\n:', labels
```

All the quantities coincide very well as what I had expected. I had also tried using `tf.Print` by writing something like:

```
logits = tf.Print(logits, [logits], message = 'logits: \n', summarize = 100)
```

immediately after defining the `logits`, so that they can get printed within the same session I run the `train_op`. However, the printing is rather messy and so I would prefer the first method of running everything in a session to obtain the values first and then printing them normally like numpy arrays.